# UITableViewController does not scroll correctly with a container view

Tags: uitableview, uitextfield, uicontainerview

I have a UITableViewController with 3 static cells. The second one is a container view. 
This container view is a UIViewController form with some UITextField's.

When I touch any of UITextField's it does not scroll to the right position, above the keyboard and in the visible area. Every textfields goes out of the screen.

I'm used to implement forms with UITableViewController and it always works good, but it's the first time I implement it with a form inside a container view. Any solutions?